# Tightening Up Ruby Code, Making Small Methods

Tags: ruby, coding-style, rubocop

I have a method that is reported by RuboCop as too long: we are only allowed seven lines per method. Here's the offending method:

```
def on(definition, visit = false, &block)
  if @active.is_a?(definition)
    block.call @active if block
    return @active
  end

  @active = definition.new
  @active.load if visit

  block.call @active if block

  @active
end
```

I was going to convert the top `if` condition to a guard clause, but I don't see how to do that.

I tried combining lines 7 and 8 into this:

```
@active = definition.new().load if visit
```

but that most definitely does not work.

I can't leave RuboCop violations active nor can I change the tolerances.

Comment: You could save three lines by replacing the first bit with `return @active if @active.is_a?(definition) && ((block &&  block.call @active) || true)` but your boss may kill you if you do.

Comment: The top if could become  `if @active.is_a?(definition) && block`

Comment: @rogerdpack, you haven't executed `block.call @active`, which undoubtedly performs some needed action.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will reduce 2 lines:

```
def on(definition, visit = false, &block)
  unless @active.is_a?(definition)  
    @active = definition.new
    @active.load if visit
  end

  block.call @active if block
  @active
end
```

Comment: The absolutely seems to do the trick. What's interesting to me is I can't decide if RuboCop is helping me produce better reading code or just more compact code. (I realize the two are not mutually exclusive.) I do thank you for your help; that works and maintains the functionality.